# How to implement wear leveling for Elm Chan's FAT FS

Tags: stm32, flash, wear-leveling

I have a working AT45DB and SST26VF driver I made and successfully implemented it for elm chan's [FAT-FS](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html). But as you know a NOR or NAND flash will wear out after 100,000 write cycles, so I have to include wear leveling to increase it "lifetime".
Do you know of any open source middleware wear leveling block?
I found [Spif](https://github.com/pellepl/spiffs)f, which is a file system with wear leveling included. But I was hoping to use Chan's FS as it is well maintained and quite robust.

Comment: FatFS is for SD/MMC cards.. not raw flash

Comment: Actually, FAT FS was made for magnetic disks. And we have uCs inside an SD/MMC which would take care of emulating it to be a magnetic disk. This emulation technique is achieved by wear leveling, bad block management, garbage collection etc.
So yes it's not for "raw" flash, but in the end an SD is a raw flash with a micro inside it.

Comment: ok, so first you will need to implement FatFs without wear leveling on the raw flash. if you can do that (big if), I would recommend static wear leveling, as its pretty straight forward

Comment: also, FatFs in not really that robust, as it doesn't journal... i've used SPIFFS in the past..its ok for non critical stuff

Comment: Yes, I got Chan's FS working with my flash drivers. And I implemented an amateur wear leveling which basically just remaps worn out blocks with new spare blocks I had kept aside. But this, as you might have noticed isn't great.
And I thought static wear leveling would be harder than dynamic WL. There would be too much book-keeping in case of static, I'm I right?

Comment: i suppose it depends how large your flash is... if you can pull of dynamic, that would be great. also, perhaps you can answer your question yourself so that the next guy can find it useful how you have solved it. I am also interested :)

Comment: @hassan789. New issue. I thought/hoped once I make a simple FTL FAT would "just" work. But today when I ran the sequence - f_mkfs, f_mount - it was successful for f_mkfs (returned FR_OK) but f_mount returned FR_NO_FILESYSTEM. It is failing when it is checking if the volume is a valid FAT boot.
*Any idea why it would give no_fs even though f_mkfs was successful. (It was successful for FAT12 and I have divided my 2048 pages into 20+1500+528, of which 1500 pages will be given to FAT. Also note 1 page is 256 bytes, so the number of logical sectors that FAT will have will be 750 as FAT min is 512)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Dataflash use a flash file system (YAFFS, SPIFFS, NIFFS) or any other. As @hassan789 said, FAT does not journal.

Comment: It also worth to mention [LittleFS](https://github.com/ARMmbed/littlefs)